# SQL How to subtract 2 row values of a same column based on same key

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

How to extract the difference of a specific column of multiple rows with same id?

Example table:

| id | prev_val | new_val | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2020-01-01 10:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2020-01-01 11:00 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2020-01-01 10:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2020-01-02 10:00 |

expected result:

| id | duration_in_hours |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 24 |

summary:
with id=1, (2020-01-01 10:00 - 2020-01-01 11:00) is 1hour;

with id=2, (2020-01-01 10:00 - 2020-01-02 10:00) is 24hour

Can we achieve this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solutions will be an effective way

```
with pd as (
select
    id,
    max(date) filter (where c.old_value = '0') as "prev",
    max(date) filter (where c.old_value = '1') as "new"
from
    table
group by
    id )
select
    id ,
    new - prev as diff
from
    pd;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use min/max subqueries. For example:

```
SELECT mn.id, (mx.maxdate - mn.mindate) as "duration",
FROM (SELECT id, max(date) as mindate FROM table GROUP BY id) mn
JOIN (SELECT id, min(date) as maxdate FROM table GROUP BY id) mx ON
   mx.id=mn.id
```

Let me know if you need help in converting duration to hours.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the difference between successive readings something like this should work

```
select a.id, a.new_val, a.date - b.date
from my_table a join my_table b 
     on a.id = b.id and a.prev_val = b.new_val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lead()/lag() [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html) to access data from the next/ previous row. You can further [subtract timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html) to give an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html) and extract the parts needed.

```
select id, floor( extract('day' from diff)*24 + extract('hour' from diff) ) "Time Difference: Hours" 
  from (select id, date_ts - lag(date_ts) over (partition by id order by date_ts) diff
          from example
       ) hd
  where diff is not null
  order by id;
```

**NOTE:**  
Your expected results, as presented, are incorrect. The results would be -1 and -24 respectively.  
DATE is a very poor choice for a column name. It is both a Postgres data type (at best leads to confusion) and a SQL Standard reserved word.